# Chef: How to debug chef cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am new to Chef so be gentle if it is obvious.

We are using *Chef* to get desired state of particular node (or instance). Debugging is bit difficult with Chef. So what I am thinking is **some how** if I get list of commands(or *shell script* or *powershell* or *msdeploy* or *any resource*) that are executed on particular instance then I can run them manually and see what exactly the problem. I am assuming at converge step this needs to be done but how I don't know.

Is there way to get list of commands to provision a instance?

Comment: It is not possible to get the executed list of commands.

Answer (score 1):

while boostrap insert -VV option . This will give detailed report of the process

```
knife bootstrap IP -VV -x username -P passwd -r role[role_id]
```

I guess this helps you

Comment: I am looking for single place where I can see all **commands**, **scripts** etc... that are used in provisioning my instance

Answer (score 0):

You can use report handlers which will collect the list of updated , failed resources and it can send it to your mail as well for every run.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use gem "debugger" https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger, I used this gem to stop the ".rb" files what ever I want, and see what was inside of any variable at that moment....
You only need to install the gem doing:

```
gem install debugger.....
```

then in the ".rb" file you need to put:

```
require "debugger"
```

and in the part of your code that you want to stop, put the word "debugger" (without "):

```
debugger
```

but I don't know if this is the solution that you are looking for....
Best wishes!

Comment: I'll try this, but what I want is not possible in the world of chef. That is what I understood.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is going on in a [chef-client](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html) run during development, you can try running `chef-client` with `-l debug` option. This provides more details from each resource while it gets executed.